# Show both types of Notification from same app across versions?

Tags: android, notifications

I am trying to show Simple Notification and Expandable Notification from the same app.
The idea is if the device is Jelly Bean or above it will show Expandable notification otherwise
show simple notification.

I am unable to install the app in older devices if i set the min version to 16
and if it is set to say 8..  expandable notification is not allowed.

So is there a work around for this?

There is not much in terms of code here..

```
int x=android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(x>=16)
{
   //Expandable Notification   
}
else
{
   //Normal Notification using NotificationCompat 
}
```

The problem is with the Version Settings with the application.
I cant use Expandable Notification with out a minimum SDK of 16
But if i set min SDK to 16  i cant install the app in older device.
Is there a way around this.

Comment: Post your codes so we can help you.

Comment: @ChuongPham i have tried to explain my situation a bit better. Hope u can help me.

Comment: Have a look at my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896615/push-notifications-service-for-android-4-4/20995515#20995515) to see if it help you. If not, post further comment so I can help you.